# Software Port Forwarding on Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, routing, port-forwarding

I have a Windows machine serving a couple web apps through Apache. I am looking for a software solution that will allow me to continue accepting requests on this computer (Windows XP) but forward the requests to port 80 to a Linux box. This Linux server is not connected to the same network, it will be connected through a private network to a second network adapter in the Windows XP machine.

Whats the most simple way to do this? I have had a quick look at XORP but it looks like overkill for what I am trying to do. Are there any solutions someone could please recommend. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a Windows Server machine, you can use the build in capabilities.

Else wise you have to use a specific software like AnalogX port mapper.

Comment: AnalogX Port Mapper is exactly what I was looking for, fantastic app. Very light weight and not as restrictive as Windows Internet Sharing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a proxyserver like Squid on your linux box and tell the clients. Increases speed and does what you want.

Comment: The Linux box is on a private network alone with the XP server and is not visible to any clients.